# Large amount of data and for loop optimization

Tags: python, json, for-loop, optimization

I have a large JSON object. A piece of it is:

```
data = [
{  
   'make': 'dacia',
   'model': 'x',
   'version': 'A',
   'typ': 'sedan',
   'infos': [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'steering wheel problems'}, 
            {'id': 32, 'name': 'ABS errors'}
   ]
},
{  
   'make': 'nissan',
   'model': 'z',
   'version': 'B',
   'typ': 'coupe',
   'infos': [
         {'id': 3,'name': 'throttle problems'}, 
         {'id': 56, 'name': 'broken handbreak'}, 
         {'id': 11, ;'name': 'missing seatbelts'}
   ]
}
]
```

I created a list of information that is interesting for me and that might occur in my JSON:

```
make = ['ford', 'fiat', 'nissan', 'suzuki', 'dacia']
model = ['x', 'y', 'z']
version = ['A', 'B', 'C']
typ = ['sedan', 'coupe', 'van', 'kombi']
```

Now I need to iterate over whole JSON `data` and count how many times certain combination of information occurs, so I created a code:

```
tab = []
s = 0
for ma in make:
   for mo in model:
      for ve in version:
        for ty in typ:
           s = sum([1 for k in data if k['make] == ma and k['model] == mo and k['version'] == ve and k['typ'] == ty)
            if s != 0:
                total.append({'make': i, 'model': j, 'version': i, 'typ': j, 'sum': s})
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm aware that it s not optimal way. Is there any way to speed-up and improve this code?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789951/search-for-combinations-in-json-nested-object

Comment: Do you want to ignore makes, models etc that aren't listed in your second code block or can we assume that all entries in `data` match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keys as a tuple (4 tuple) and implement your own counter

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)

for i in data:
    res[i['make'],i['model'], i['version'], i['typ']] += 1
```

You can then filter of combinations you don't need form this `res` you can have an `if` to check if the 4 tuple is from the combination set you need to filter. So making this linear.

Edit, you can also use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
res = Counter((i['make'],i['model'], i['version'], i['typ']) for i in data)
```

If you have a combination set called `combinations` then adding the filter can be something like. Python 3.8+

```
combinations = {your_combination_set_that_has_tuples}
res = Counter(key for i in data if (key := (i['make'],i['model'], i['version'], i['typ'])) in combinations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

- Groupby in Pandas to generate groups of combinations
- Count function to count the size of each group
- Avoids Python for loop which is slow for large lists in JSON structures

Correct Data (posted has an error i.e. spurious ';')

```
data = [
{  
   'make': 'dacia',
   'model': 'x',
   'version': 'A',
   'typ': 'sedan',
   'infos': [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'steering wheel problems'}, 
            {'id': 32, 'name': 'ABS errors'}
   ]
},
{  
   'make': 'nissan',
   'model': 'z',
   'version': 'B',
   'typ': 'coupe',
   'infos': [
         {'id': 3,'name': 'throttle problems'}, 
         {'id': 56, 'name': 'broken handbreak'}, 
         {'id': 11, 'name': 'missing seatbelts'}
   ]
}
]
```

Count Combinations

```
import pandas as pd

# JSON to Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Groupby desired properties and
# Count size of each group
result = df.groupby(['make', 'model', 'version', 'typ']).count()
print(result)

# Output (shows combinations of make, model, version, type and count)
                                  infos
make    model   version typ 
dacia   x       A       sedan         1
nissan  z       B       coupe         1
```